# Python embedded web server with client authentication

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cherrypy, m2crypto

I need to build a python web server which supports 2 different types of users :

- "Super admins", which get full access to the admin panel when they connect using a pre-configured laptop/browser.
- Admins, which get limited access to the admin panel and can connect using only a username/password combo.

I'm thinking SSL client authentication is a possible solution for authentifying the technicians.

Note that the web server will be embedded in a product and will not have internet access, so cannot connect to a CA.

### Is SSL client authentication a good solution, or is there a simpler, or better option?

Here's what I've found...

**CherryPy** seems to be a very nice, simple python web server. However, it does not seem to support client authentification.

**M2Crypto** seems like a very complete library which supports all forms of SSL authentification, however I haven't found a detailed example of how to set up a python web server using M2Crypto for SSL client authentification.

**pyOpenSSL** seems to be dead.

I also found a recipe, which explains how to set up a python web server with SSL. However...

> With this recipe, only the server is authenticated while the client
>   remains unauthenticated (i.e. the server will not request a client
>   certificate).
>
> *Source : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/*

### Can someone point me in the right direction or link to a well documented implementation of what I'm trying to do?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you not embedded a 'real' webserver like lighttpd or cherokee? Then use a micro python framework

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the twisted libraries: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/index.html

There is a simple echoservl_ssl and echoclient_ssl example in the link as well.

Optionally, bundle apache + any web framework and you're golden. There are loads of articles online about small embedded web servers.

Comment: In the examples, it seems like the client authenticates the server. I would like the server to authenticate the client.